# Apache redirect works except for index?

Tags: apache-2.4, 301-redirect

I'm trying to redirect my old site to a particular url on my new site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@info.com
ServerName old.dev
ServerAlias www.old.dev

Redirect 301 / http://new.dev/old
</VirtualHost>
```

However old.dev redirects to new.dev instead of new.dev/old.
All other paths except / redirect to new.dev/old correctly. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It turns out Chrome was the culprit. Same request in safari redirected to correct url.